# Saving fill with np.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to save a random data I generated using Numpy but I keep getting error

No.savetxt = ("Random-Test-Data.csv", random_test_array, fmt='%s', delimiter=",")

I keep getting syntax error just after "fmt"

Comment: What is this data structure on the right hand side supposed to be? It's not a tuple, not a dict, nor a numpy array...

Comment: It is supposed to be a numpy array

Comment: Do you know how to create numpy arrays then? [Look here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.creation.html)

Comment: Use `np.savetxt(file_name, array, fmt=...., delimiter=...)`.  `savetxt=...` is plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i have been able to trace back my code and found where the error was coming from, it should have been np.savetxt("Random_Test_From_Numpy.csv", random_test_data, fmt='%s', delimiter=',') rather than what i am on my question